# p5.js onclick redraw the rectangle

Tags: p5.js

I would like to redraw the rectangle inside the circle when it is clicked; can anyone suggest an idea?

```
function setup() {
createCanvas(700, 500);
  // Starts in the middle
  x = width / 2;
  y = height / 2;
}

function draw() {
    background(10);
    stroke(1000);
    fill(10);
    ellipse(x, y, 300, 300);

    rect(80, 80, 100, 50);
    rect(550, 180, 100, 50);
    rect(150, 400, 100, 50);
}

function mousePressed() {
    //question
}
```

remove() wipes out the entire canvas.

Comment: Did you want the mouseclick to work only when clicked inside the circle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "**re**draw the rectangle inside the circle", when you don't have it drawn at all initially, but I guess you just meant "draw". Also, not sure if you wanted all of that to happen only on click at inside the circle, but if my presumptions are ok, then below is the solution.

It will draw the rectangle at the place where you clicked, provided that you clicked inside the circle. As you can see, I moved all of the code from the `draw()` into `setup()`, since you don't really need it being refreshed 30 times a sec. If you do, then a slightly diff solution would be needed (the second one below).

```
var myCircle;
var x, y, radius;
radius = 300;

function setup() {

    createCanvas(700, 500);
    // Starts in the middle
    x = width / 2;
    y = height / 2;

    background(10);
    stroke(255);
    fill(100);

    myCircle = ellipse(x, y, radius, radius);

    fill(50);
    rect(80, 80, 100, 50);
    rect(550, 180, 100, 50);
    rect(150, 400, 100, 50);

}

function draw() {
}

// global mousePressed handler - reacts on click anywhere on the PAGE (not just on canvas)
function mousePressed() {
    if (insideCircle()) {
        rect(mouseX-50, mouseY-25, 100, 50);
    }
    return false;
}

/**
* returns true if the mouse was clicked inside a circle (simply checks the distance of the click from the circle's center)
*/
function insideCircle() {
    return Math.sqrt(sq(mouseX-x) + sq(mouseY-y)) < radius/2 ? true : false;
}
```

**Solution with constant redrawing of the canvas:**

```
var x, y, radius;
radius = 300;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(700, 500);
    // Starts in the middle
    x = width / 2;
    y = height / 2;

}

function draw() {
    background(10);
    stroke(255);
    fill(100);    

    ellipse(x, y, radius, radius);

    fill(50);
    rect(80, 80, 100, 50);
    rect(550, 180, 100, 50);
    rect(150, 400, 100, 50);    
    if (mouseIsPressed) {
        if (insideCircle()) {
            rect(mouseX-50, mouseY-25, 100, 50);
        }
    }
}

// global mousePressed handler - reacts on click anywhere on the PAGE (not just on canvas)
function mousePressed() {
    // ignore it
}

/**
* returns true if the mouse was clicked inside a circle (simply checks the distance of the click from the circle's center)
*/
function insideCircle() {
    return Math.sqrt(sq(mouseX-x) + sq(mouseY-y)) < radius/2 ? true : false;
}
```